# Deserialize JSON value without name

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

How can I deserialize a string in C# that only have values and no name. It looks like this: The problem is that this stream of string does not have name and uses array.

```html
{
  "result": {
    "14400": [
      [
        1502985600,
        262.18,
        262.18,
        257,
        257,
        1096.0131
      ],
      [
        1503000000,
        257,
        261.33,
        254.8,
        257,
        1130.5897
      ]
   ],
 "14405": [
      [
        1503014400,
        258.03,
        261.5,
        257.01,
        257.01,
        520.7805
      ],
      [
        1503028800,
        258,
        260.98,
        252.4,
        259.56,
        298.5658
      ],
   ]
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: Must be a dupe, right ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create a class like

```
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<int,List<List<double>>> Result { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize as

```
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Comment: @napi15 why don't you try it?

Comment: I'm just a man-in-the-middle that is surprised and impressed by your 2 line solution while I spent 10 min trying to build mine :)

Comment: @napi15 it could have been also one-liner but not much readable. `var dict = JObject.Parse(json)["result"].ToObject<Dictionary<int, List<List<double>>>>();`

Answer (score 1):

I see it's an array, you could create a  method to parse the class out of given JArray.

The Jason data

```
  public void methpod()
    {

string json ="Your jason value " 

        var factory = new Factory();
        var suggest = factory.Create(json);

        Console.WriteLine(suggest);
    }
```

Make a class  as suggested :

```
public class Factory
{
    public Evan Create(string json)
    {
        var array = JArray.Parse(json);
        string search = array[0].ToString();
        string[] terms = array[1].ToArray().Select(item => item.ToString()).ToArray();

        return new Evan{Search = search, Terms = terms};
    }
}
```

and another

```
public class Evan
{
    public string Search { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Terms { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Search={0},Terms=[{1}]", 
            Search, string.Join(",", Terms));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tip

If you have JSON that you want to deserialize, and you don't have the class to deserialize it into, Visual Studio 2019 can automatically generate the class you need:

Copy the JSON that you need to deserialize.
Create a class file and delete the template code.
Choose Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes.
The result is a class that you can use for your deserialization target

Comment: While this is helpful in normal circumstances, it isn't helpful here where the results have numbers as the property names