# How do I convert json string without name with Newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, json.net

Json string

```
{"geonames":[{"continent":"EU","capital":"Andorra la Vella","languages":"ca","geonameId":3041565,"south":42.42849259876837,"isoAlpha3":"AND","north":42.65604389629997,"fipsCode":"AN","population":"84000","east":1.7865427778319827,"isoNumeric":"020","areaInSqKm":"468.0","countryCode":"AD","west":1.4071867141112762,"countryName":"Andorra","continentName":"Europe","currencyCode":"EUR"},{"continent":"AS","capital":"Abu Dhabi","languages":"ar-AE,fa,en,hi,ur","geonameId":290557,"south":22.633329391479492,"isoAlpha3":"ARE","north":26.08415985107422,"fipsCode":"AE","population":"4975593","east":56.38166046142578,"isoNumeric":"784","areaInSqKm":"82880.0","countryCode":"AE","west":51.58332824707031,"countryName":"United Arab Emirates","continentName":"Asia","currencyCode":"AED"},{"continent":"AS","capital":"Kabul","languages":"fa-AF,ps,uz-AF,tk","geonameId":1149361,"south":29.377472,"isoAlpha3":"AFG","north":38.483418,"fipsCode":"AF","population":"29121286","east":74.879448,"isoNumeric":"004","areaInSqKm":"647500.0","countryCode":"AF","west":60.478443,"countryName":"Afghanistan","continentName":"Asia","currencyCode":"AFN"},{"continent":"AF","capital":"Harare","languages":"en-ZW,sn,nr,nd","geonameId":878675,"south":-22.417738,"isoAlpha3":"ZWE","north":-15.608835,"fipsCode":"ZI","population":"13061000","east":33.056305,"isoNumeric":"716","areaInSqKm":"390580.0","countryCode":"ZW","west":25.237028,"countryName":"Zimbabwe","continentName":"Africa","currencyCode":"ZWL"}]}
```

How can I force Newtonsoft to parse the data?

Exception
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'App.Geonames' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

**UPDATED**

> Solution

Controller

```
string GeoNamesCountry = "http://api.geonames.org/countryInfo?username=justlearntutors&type=json";

string GeoNamesCountryResult = "";
using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
{
    GeoNamesCountryResult = webclient.DownloadString(GeoNamesCountry);
}

GeonamesObject geonamesObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeonamesObject>(GeoNamesCountryResult);
```

Model

```
public class GeonamesObject
{
    public GeonamesCountry[] geonames { get; set; }
}

public class GeonamesCountry
{
    public string countryCode { get; set; }
    public string countryName { get; set; }
    public string isoNumeric { get; set; }
    public string isoAlpha3 { get; set; }
    public string fipsCode { get; set; }
    public string continent { get; set; }
    public string continentName { get; set; }
    public string capital { get; set; }
    public string areaInSqKm { get; set; }
    public string population { get; set; }
    public string currencyCode { get; set; }
    public string languages { get; set; }
    public int geonameId { get; set; }
    public string west { get; set; }
    public string north { get; set; }
    public string east { get; set; }
    public string south { get; set; }
    public string postalCodeFormat { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What a huge sample data. Anyway, would you mind sharing a snippet of your code.

Comment: Probably a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103849/deserialize-json-value-without-name)

Comment: Not entirely sure what the question is here because I can successfully deserialize your json using your models and your code. Can you please post a [mcve] that shows the problem? I pasted all your code into LINQPad and it run successfully, and produced a `GeonamesObject` with 250 `GeonamesCountry` objects in the `geonames` array. In short, your code works, **what is the question?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use visual studio to auto-generate classes based your json string.
Copy your json string, go

> Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes (Note: Your Json string needs to be valid)

then it will create classes for you (note: Use `JsonProperty` attribute, to to serialize/desrialize the member with specified name)

```
public class Rootobject
{
    [JsonProperty("geonames")]
    public Geoname[] Geonames { get; set; }
}


public class Geoname
{
    [JsonProperty("continent")]
    public string Continent { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("capital")]
    public string Capital { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("languages")]
    public string Languages { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("geonameId")]
    public int GeonameId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("south")]
    public float South { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isoAlpha3")]
    public string IsoAlpha3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("north")]
    public float North { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fipsCode")]
    public string FipsCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("population")]
    public string Population { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("east")]
    public float East { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isoNumeric")]
    public string IsoNumeric { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("areaInSqKm")]
    public string AreaInSqKm { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("countryCode")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("west")]
    public float West { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("countryName")]
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("continentName")]
    public string ContinentName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currencyCode")]
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }

}
```

then deserialize it:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json_string);
```

Comment: Very helpful. Can I do the same with xml and csv?

Comment: There is option for xml: _Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes_. Also remember that you json or xml strings should be valid.

Answer (score 0):

kindly check this things should work

```
GeonamesObject geonamesObject = new GeonamesObject();
geonamesObject.geonames = 
 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Geonames>>(GeoNamesCountryResult);
```